# Liquibase: MySqlSyntaxErrorException: table already exists

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, liquibase

I have seen several related questions and their answers, but it is not helping my case.

I have a Spring boot application, where I have created entities using Jhipster, plus I have added some manual changelog changesets myself.

I have a Doctor entity, which contains a One-to-Many uni-directional relationship with 'Specialty' where 'Doctor' is the owner of the relationship. So I specified a Join table that will store Doctor and Specialty foreign keys.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="doctor_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="specialty_id")
)
private List<Specialty> specialties = new ArrayList<>();
```

For this, I added a changelog file, that even contains the  tag to ignore specialty if it already exists,

```
<changeSet id="20150415081455" author="waqas">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="20150415081221" author="waqas">

    <createTable tableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY">

        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="doctor_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="specialty_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="doctor_id"
                             baseTableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY"
                             constraintName="fk_doctor_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="T_DOCTOR"/>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="specialty_id"
                             baseTableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY"
                             constraintName="fk_specialty_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="T_SPECIALTY"/>
</changeSet>
```

Then, I create a new database with no tables and run the application, but I get the following exception:

```
(Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [io/aurora/ams/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20150415081221_added_entity_Doctor_Specialty.xml::20150415081221::waqas:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 't_doctor_specialty' already exists
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at io.aurora.ams.Application.main(Application.java:64) [bin/:na]

Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20150415081221_added_entity_Doctor_Specialty.xml::20150415081221::waqas:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 't_doctor_specialty' already exists
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:586) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:43) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:200) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 't_doctor_specialty' already exists
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1227) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1210) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:550) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 't_doctor_specialty' already exists
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.execute(StatementProxy.java:83) ~[HikariCP-2.2.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementJavassistProxy.execute(StatementJavassistProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-2.2.5.jar:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
```

I will like to mention that the relationship is only mentioned in the 20150415081221_added_entity_Doctor_Specialty.xml changelog, not in Doctor.

I have searched a lot but not sure what might be causing this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are other tables created? By Hibernate, or everything is in liquibase changesets?

Comment: In liquibase changesets. Though I created the Doctor entity using JHipster, but the OneToMany relationships were not specified anywhere. So I had to create a separate changelog for Doctor_Specialty myself.

And if I remove the changelog, the Doctor_Specialty table is never created

Comment: Table is been created by jhipster at the beginning and after that liquibase is running trying to create the same table. That's the reason why you are getting the error.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez: That was my assumption too. But if I remove the changelog file, then the table never gets created. This happens for every one to many relationship, even if I have created manually (without using Jhipster). Also, I think it was wierd that when using Jhipster, the one-to-many relationships are not specified at all in liquibase changelogs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though I am still not sure what the exact problem is with Liquibase regarding this error, the workaround using preCondition tag was not working because of a constraint, mentioned in Liquibase documentation:

"Outside a changeset (e.g. at the beginning of the change log), only HALT and WARN are possible values."

Placing the preCondition inside the changeSet right before createTable was what I was missing.

```
<changeSet id="20150415081221" author="waqas">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="T_DOCTOR_SPECIALTY">...
```

Answer (score 1):

It might have happened that you must have mentioned your table name in the Hibernate annotation for @Table(name="Table_Name") and it must have stored it. So, to resolve this you can delete all the contents of the data folder and restart you server and try to run your application.

Worked for me as I have not executed the script before.